# Difference between Generalized linear modelling and regular logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, glm, logistic-regression

I am trying to perform logistic regression for my data. I came to know about glm. What is the actual difference between glm and regular logistic regression?
What are the pros and cons of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main benefit of GLM over logistic regression is overfitting avoidance. GLM usually try to extract linearity between input variables and then avoid overfitting of your model. Overfitting means very good performance on training data and poor performance on test data.

Answer (score 6):

Logistic Regression is [a special case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Binomial_data) of Generalized Linear Models. GLMs is a class of models, parametrized by a *link function*. If you choose logit link function, you'll get Logistic Regression.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm interested in knowing the benefits of glm over regular logistic regression. Because we can even perform logistic regression without GLM.